Internal effects of loading and cut in an object to find critical points
I need to find critical points in an object. But i dont know where to cut. The object is part of a forklift, the forks and the trolley are made as one Free Body Diagram. I don't know if this is the place to post this, but I hope someone will explain and help. The forklift also experiences a load force F_L.

What's a "critical point"? What is a "cut"? I'm an EE so I don't do much of this sort of mechanical calculation but would be interested to know.
